# só um commandbuttom funciona

Tags: jsf-2.2

```
<ui:define name="titulo da pagina">Cadastro De Bairro</ui:define>

<ui:define name="miolo">
    <div class="conteudo_do_modulo">
        <h:form id="Salvar" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1" lang="pt_BR">
            <fieldset>
                <ui:fragment rendered="#{!BairroBean.editar}">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Cadastrar novo Bairro" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{BairroBean.nomeNovo}" id="novoBairro" />
                    <h:commandButton value="Salvar"
                        action="#{BairroBean.salvarBairro()}" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </ui:fragment>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{BairroBean.editar}">
                <h:outputLabel value="Valor Atual" for="nomeAntigo" />
                <h:inputText value="#{BairroBean.nomeAntigo}" readonly="true" id="nomeAntigo" />
                <h:inputHidden value="#{BairroBean.nomeAntigo}" id="valorAntigo" />
                <br /> <br />
                <h:outputLabel value="Digite O Novo Bairro" for="novoBairro2" />
                <h:inputText value="#{BairroBean.nomeNovo}" id="novoBairro2" />
                <h:commandButton value="Alterar" action="#{BairroBean.editarBairro()}" />
        </ui:fragment>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>   
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

pessoal estou com uma duvida, porque somente um commandbuttom funciona
ja resolvi o prblema mas queria saber o porque. mesmo eu dizendo quando eles devem renderizar somente o botao 'Salvar' funciona, tive que separar
em duas form para resolver.

1)-tentei tirar os ui:fragment ai funcionou, antes era um ui:fragment para  cada botao com a condiçao para renderizar.

2) tentei deixar um bloco com outputformat e fazer a logica tb não deu.
so da certo de deixar um bloco com ui:fragment e o outro para aparecer quando quiser

3) tentei até fazer a logica nos botoes 'salvar' e 'alterar' tb nao deu.

metodos conferem, tanto que foi so dividir em 2 forms e deu certo.
os beans são escopo de requisição.

Obrigado a todos ^^

Comment: Provavelmente por causa [disto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091070/two-hcommandbutton-in-a-hform-one-work-and-one-doesnt)

Comment: é rapaz , confere d+++++ essa reposta. muito obrigado, mesmo tendo resolvido o problema tinha que saber o porque vlww